# Checkbox que puxe conteúdo de um post custom type

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Tenho um *custom post type* de malhas (aqui será cadastrado todas as malhas de produtos) e tenho um outro custom post type de produtos (onde será listado todos os produtos).

O que eu gostaria de fazer: nesse *custom post type* de produtos ter um campo personalizado de checkbox que lista-se todos os itens do *custom post type* de malhas. Como eu posso fazer isso?

*OBS.: Não quero usar categorias.*

Answer (score 3):

A maneira de fazer isso é adicionar um Meta Box personalizado com [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) e dentro do box listar os posts do seu CPT usando [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). E a informação será gravada como um Custom Field usando [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). Note que se o Custom Field começa com um *underscore* (`_NomeDoField`), ele é invisível no box padrão de custom fields.

Neste exemplo, o Meta Box é adicionado aos Posts normais e a listagem é de entradas do CPT Portfolio. Ajuste conforme necessário nos locais indicados.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Listagem de CPT em Meta Box
 * Plugin URI: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16674/201
 * Author: brasofilo
 */

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_box_sopt_16606' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_postdata_sopt_16606', 10, 2 );

function add_box_sopt_16606() 
{
    add_meta_box(
        'sectionid_sopt_16606',
        __( 'CPT Associado' ), 
        'cpt_box_sopt_16606',
        'post', # <--- Ajuste CPT
        'side'
    );
}

function cpt_box_sopt_16606() 
{
    global $post;

    // Puxar todos as entradas do CPT
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'portfolio', # <--- Ajuste CPT
        'post_status' => 'publish,future'
    );
    $get_posts = get_posts( $args );

    // Valor gravado ou default
    $saved = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cpt_associado', true );
    if( !$saved )
        $saved = array();

    // Segurança
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'noncename_sopt_16606' );

    if( $get_posts )
    {
        foreach ( $get_posts as $cpt_post ) 
        {
            printf(
                '<input type="checkbox" name="_cpt_associado[%1$s]" value="%1$s" id="_cpt_associado[%1$s]" %3$s />'.
                '<label for="_cpt_associado[%1$s]"> %2$s ' .
                '</label><br>',
                esc_attr( $cpt_post->ID ),
                esc_html( $cpt_post->post_title ),
                checked( in_array( $cpt_post->ID, $saved ), true, false )
            );
        }
    }
    else
        echo '<strong>O CPT não tem entradas</strong>';
}


function save_postdata_sopt_16606( $post_id, $post_object ) 
{
    // Não é nosso tipo, sair fora
    if ( 'post' !== $post_object->post_type ) # <--- Ajuste CPT
        return;

    // Fazendo auto save?
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // Segurança
    if ( 
        !isset( $_POST['noncename_sopt_16606'] ) 
        || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename_sopt_16606'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) 
        )
        return;

    // Gravar ou deletar
    if ( isset( $_POST['_cpt_associado'] )  )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_cpt_associado', $_POST['_cpt_associado'] );
    else 
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_cpt_associado' );
}
```

**Resultado**
[image: meta box listando entradas do cpt]

<sub>Código adaptado de [List of Posts in a Custom Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94716/12615)</sub>